# Signification de « maître chien » dans « Surveillance de la résidence par un maître chien »

Tags: usage, france

> Surveillance de la résidence par un maître chien :
>
> Lors du dernier conseil syndical, il a été décidé à compter du 20 juillet 2013 la surveillance quotidienne (jour et nuit) de la résidence (halls et sous-sols) par un maître chien face aux actes de vandalismes de ces derniers jours.

Je sais le sens du mot composé *maître chien* (dog trainer sans erreur de ma part). Par contre je me demande quelle est sa signification dans ce contexte. (Je pense qu'il concerne une sorte de sentinelle avec un chien.)

Nota bene :

Pourquoi maître chien et pas maître-chien, voire maître des chiens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans l'article de Wikipédia concernant le sujet des [maitres-chien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%C3%AEtre-chien_en_France), on s'aperçoit que le terme désigne une occupation à deux facettes, celle d'une personne versée dans la formation des chiens, en d'autres termes personne qui entraine les chiens bien que pas professionnellement et sous la direction d'un professionnel du dressage, et celle de personne responsable d'une mission de sécurité avec un chien entrainé, en d'autres terme **agent (de sécurité) cynophile** ce qui constitue le volet essentiel de l'occupation.<sup>1</sup>

Plusieurs termes synonymes sont employés : **Maitre-chien, Agent cynophile, conducteur de chien**.

Le terme « agent de sécurité/ maitre-chien » est aussi employé.

Ce terme ne se trouve pas dans le TLFi ; cependant, dans le Larousse en ligne on trouve la définition suivante :

> Responsable du dressage et de l'emploi d'un chien militaire.

Cela confirme que le terme a au moins deux acceptions, dont celles considérées de façon générale.

L'orthographe « maitre-chien » est pratiquement la seule dans tous les textes que je peux trouver (mis à part le tréma sur le i qui est conservé, mais la réforme 90 l'enlève). « Maitre des chiens » signifierait « maitre de tous les chiens en général » ; la construction libre est aussi utilisable dans un contexte approprié ; par exemple si quelqu'un possède trois chiens et ces trois chiens en groupe commettent un crime comme possiblement rentrer dans le poulailler d'un voisin pour y manger des poules, alors lorsque l'on capture ces chiens on peut se demander qui est *le maitre des chiens* ; il ne s'agit dans ce cas que de « propriétaire des chiens » ; cela est bien différent de la relation qui existe entre un maitre-chien et son animal.

La construction particulière ressemble à l'anglais mais elle est typique de la syntaxe française ;

- trains the dog (objet) ; donc « dog trainer »
- dresse, commande le chien (objet), est maitre du chien ; donc « maitre-chien »

Justement, la forme particulière permet une claire différence entre les deux termes, « maitre des chiens » et  « maitre-chien ». Il est intéressant de noter que ce pourrait être une construction de type récent mais ce n'est pas le cas.

Des composés sur le modèle courant (TLFi)

- maitre de forges.
- maitre d'ouvrage, maitre de l'ouvrage
- maitre d'oeuvre, maitre de l'oeuvre
- maitre d'hôtel
- maitre de ballet
- maitre d'équipage.
- maitre, maitresse d'internat
- maitre répétiteur
- maitre, maitresse d'atelier; maitre charpentier; maitre menuisier

Composés sur le modèle de « maitre-chien » (TLFi)
- Maître(-)compagnon, maître(-)garçon, maître(-)ouvrier, maître(-)porion, maître(-)valet, etc. (*qui a autorité sur*)

Autre modèle (user **jlliagre**)

- Maître-nageur, maître-queux, maître-assistant : (qui maîtrise une discipline)

<sub><sup>1</sup> Détails concernant les deux aspects de la profession dus à user **Mouviciel**</sub>

Comment: *Maître-nageur*, *maître-queux*, *maître-assistant* : (qui maîtrise une discipline)

Comment: J'hésiterais à parler de _deux acceptions_. Le dressage et l'emploi d'un chien sont deux volets d'une même compétence. Pour établir une confiance mutuelle optimale, un maître-chien se doit d'entraîner le chien qui l'accompagne dans ses missions de sécurité.

Comment: @mouviciel Je ne suis pas si sûr de cela ; on trouve par exemple ceci :«  Si le maître-chien souhaite rajouter un chien ou changer de chien, il doit effectuer avec ce dernier une formation de 70 heures.». Il est clair que dans ce cas le maitre chien n'a pas pris en charge la formation complète de son nouveau chien, 70 heures ne suffisent pas ; il semblerait que certain de ces professionnels ne s'occuperaient que de dressage. [ref](https://www.lemagduchien.com/dossier-32-agent-securite-cynophile-maitre-chien.html)

Comment: @mouviciel Le lien suivant confirme qu'une spécialité connexe existe, mais il s'agit de celle de dresseur de chien, ce que tout maitre chien peut prétendre devenir après quelques années d'expérience ; donc, il ne doit être question que d'une professsion. ([ref](http://www.canisball.fr/devenir-maitre-chien-agent-cynophile), voir « les évolutions de carrière »)